# MS Access OpenRedcordset reading wrong string

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, recordset

General explanation:

1. my query *2_Total* returns a single value:

   [image: Access Return]
2. Run the VBA function that exports the query to an excel file:

   [image: My Excel Output]

**Problem:** `OpenRecordset` is not reading the correct query. My query should be exported to my excel file. Yet My VBA is pointing at wrong stuff.

My guess is that the line `qry.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo_SO_SalesHistory]"` is not providing sufficient information?

**SQL**

```sql
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) 
BETWEEN [Forms]![RUN]![textBeginOrderDate] AND [Forms]![RUN]![textendorderdate]));
```

**VBA**

```vb
Option Compare Database

Option Explicit
Public Function TRANS2()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim acRng As Variant
    Dim xlRow As Integer

    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qry As QueryDef
    Dim rst As Recordset
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter
    Dim strSQL As String

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\J\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Totals")

    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)
    Set qry = db.QueryDefs("2_Total")

    strSQL = strSQL & " [dbo_SO_SalesHistory].[InvoiceDate] Between #" _
    & [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate] & "# And #" _
    & [Forms]![Run]![textendorderdate] & "#"

    qry.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo_SO_SalesHistory]"

    Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("2_Total", dbOpenDynaset)

    Dim c As Integer
    c = 11   'C is the one that stores column number, in which c=1 means column A, 11 is for column K, 12 for Column L
    xlRow = xlRow + 11

     Do Until rst.EOF
        For Each acRng In rst.Fields
            xlWS.Cells(xlRow, c).Formula = acRng
            c = c + 1
        Next acRng
        xlRow = xlRow + 1
        c = 1
        rst.MoveNext
        If xlRow > 25 Then GoTo rq_Exit
    Loop


rq_Exit:
    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: You code is extremely confusing :  1. you prepare a query in the string `strSQL` that is not used anywhere. 2. you define a QueryDef `qry` that is not used anywhere. 3. The only thing you output in your Excel file is the contain of your `rst` recordset that grabs the result your 2_Total query, which returns only one row and column, which has thus nothing to do with the Excel file contain you have shown. All this is a mystery to me.

Comment: @ThomasG No.3 is the problem/issue I have now. My 2_Total query returns a single value, which is what I hope to export to my Excel file. But it is printing out irrelevant string on the excel file.

Comment: @ThomasG Any advice on this issue would be highly appreciated. I'm a newbie to VBA. Appreciate that you pointed out some issues on my code

Comment: If all you want is a single aggregate value, why are you bothering with QueryDefs? Open a recordset to the full, filtered SQL statement. I also do not understand the Excel looping just to export a single value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider releasing the *querydef* before `OpenRecordset` as the recordset call uses the last saved instance of query and not the changes to the SQL since you never official save it:

```vb
qry.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo_SO_SalesHistory]"
Set qry = Nothing

Set rst = db.OpenRecordset("2_Total", dbOpenDynaset)
```

Or better yet, open the recordset directly from querydef, using [QueryDef.OpenRecordset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822070.aspx):

```vb
qry.SQL = "SELECT * FROM [dbo_SO_SalesHistory]"

Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

---

But as @ThomasG comments, carefully check your code and integrate above suggestion accordingly. This `SELECT` statement does not seem to output a one-row, one-column resultset. However your posted SQL does return one row/one-column aggregate. I suspect you intended:

```vb
strSQL = "SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold" _
          & " FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory" _
          & " WHERE [dbo_SO_SalesHistory].[InvoiceDate] BETWEEN #" _
          & [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate] & "# AND #" _
          & [Forms]![Run]![textendorderdate] & "#"

qry.SQL = strSQL
```

However, I suggest using parameterization for cleaner, safer, maintainable code.

```vb
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [BeginDate] Datetime, [EndDate] Datetime;" _
          & " SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold" _
          & " FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory" _
          & " WHERE [dbo_SO_SalesHistory].[InvoiceDate]" _
          & " BETWEEN [BeginDate] AND [EndDate];"

qry.SQL = strSQL

qry![BeginDate] = [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate]
qry![EndDate] = [Forms]![Run]![textendorderdate]

Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

And yes, above VBA string can and should be saved on its own as an Access query object. So no need to re-write SQL each time. Just bind different dynamic params each time!

```vb
Set qry = db.QueryDefs("2_Total")     ' ABOVE STRING SQL STATEMENT WITH PARAMETERS

qry![BeginDate] = [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate]
qry![EndDate] = [Forms]![Run]![textendorderdate]

Set rst = qry.OpenRecordset(dbOpenDynaset)
```

Comment: Thank you so so much. I can't thank you enough. You are awesome and amazing. Thank you so much for your time and advise.

Comment: I'm so sorry but can I ask you a follow-up question? I'm getting Item not found in this collection error on the line, qry!BeginDate = [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate]. Any advice on this will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure query begins with `PARAMETERS [BeginDate] Datetime, [EndDate] Datetime;`? Try bracketing `[...]` the names. See update.

Comment: Sorry I am not sure by BeginDate query. I'm terribly sorry for my stupidity. I tried 'qry![BeginDate] = [Forms]![Run]![textBeginOrderDate]' and got the same error message. 
I have an interactive access form to filter a query by date range (start Date ex) 8/1/2017 and End Date) ex 8/31/2017) Then my query (2_Total) returns a single value. Would this help you clarify how I get the parameters??

Comment: Make sure your *2_Total* query looks exactly like the VBA *strSQL* (of course without the quotes, underscore, equality, or ampersand). You need `PARAMETERS...` placed before the `SELECT` and the `WHERE` clause changed. Do not use your old SQL version.

Answer (score 1):

I may have deleted too much, but if "2_Totals" SQL code is precisely:

```sql
SELECT Sum(dbo_SO_SalesHistory.DollarsSold) AS SumOfDollarsSold
FROM dbo_SO_SalesHistory
WHERE (((dbo_SO_SalesHistory.InvoiceDate) 
BETWEEN [Forms]![RUN]![textBeginOrderDate] AND [Forms]![RUN]![textendorderdate]));
```

Then the following code will lookup that value and place it in the referenced cell in Excel. There was a loop, that didn't seem to make sense since the query returns a single value so I removed it. I don't understand why you find the last row but then add 11 rows to it, but if it changes the wrong cell, comment out the `xlRow = xlRow + 11` line.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Function TRANS2()

    Dim xlApp As Excel.Application
    Dim xlWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim xlWS As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim xlRow As Integer
    Dim dblOutput As Double
    Dim db As DAO.Database

    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set xlApp = New Excel.Application
    Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\J\Desktop\August 2017.xlsx")
    Set xlWS = xlWB.Worksheets("Totals")

    xlRow = (xlWS.Columns("K").End(xlDown).Row)

    dblOutput = DLookup("[SumOfDollarsSold]", "2_Totals")

    xlRow = xlRow + 11

    xlWS.Cells(xlRow, 11).Value = dblOutput

rq_Exit:
    Set xlWS = Nothing
    xlWB.Close acSaveYes
    Set xlWB = Nothing
    xlApp.Quit
    Set xlApp = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: Could use DSum() on the original raw data and include date filter in the DSum().

Comment: @June7 true, it seems though that the criteria is already built into the saved query, so it seemed easier to just use the query.

Comment: Also true. Tho, I never use dynamic parameterized queries. DSum() may mean 1 less query object.